# Is indexing into NodeList via [] reliable and (ideally) documented?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

Is indexing into a `NodeList` using `[]` rather than `item()` completely reliable-cross browser, and (separately) is it documented anywhere? E.g.:

```
var firstDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
```

As far as I can tell, the most up-to-date definition of the `NodeList` interface is [here in DOM3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), and the most recent documentation of the JavaScript bindings is in the [DOM2 version](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/ecma-script-binding.html). I'm not seeing anything about indexing into `NodeList`s via `[]`, but I see people doing it all the time (and I've done it myself frequently, but always a bit nervously).

So I [tried it out](http://jsbin.com/ukuyef) on a bunch of browsers, including IE6, and it works a champ everywhere I tried it (IE6, IE9, Chrome 16, Firefox 10, Firefox 5, Opera 11, Safari 5, Konqueror 4.7, Epiphany 3.0, Midori 0.4). Which is great, except I don't have dozens of edge-case browsers around.

So I'm looking for input from anyone who's been down this road before. Is it completely reliable cross-browser, and ideally is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [one of your links](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177%20DOM3) *(my emphasis)*:

> The items in the NodeList are accessible via an **integral index**, starting from 0.

And from [another link](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/ecma-script-binding.html%20DOM2):

> The NodeList object has the following methods:
>
> item(index)
>   This method returns a Node object.
>   The index parameter is of type Number.
>   Note: This object can also be dereferenced using **square bracket notation (e.g. obj [ 1 ] )**.
>   Dereferencing with an integer index is equivalent to invoking the item method with that
>   index.

So yes, it is documented. And reliable.

Comment: Gah! It's **right there**! \*facepalm\* And it goes [*all the way back to DOM1*](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-536297177). For the record, I'm normally better at reading things than this. Yeesh.

Comment: As we say in Sweden: The first things that go blind are the eyes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is absolutely reliably cross-browser. Either that, or most of the JavaScript I've ever written breaks, and jQuery too :)

For at least *some* documentation, see the [Mozilla Developer Network JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList):

> Returns an item in the list by its index, or `null` if out-of-bounds. **Equivalent to `nodeList[idx]`**